# Gap Occurring between tooltip and the graph in Combined Column and Scatter Graph

Tags: reactjs, highcharts

I need one help from you regarding the highcharts Column Graph and Scatter graph tooltip alignment.

I have a column graph and a scatter graph. which have the combined tooltip. If I have 2 graph values with out having null or zero then I able to show the tooltip correctly. But if I have one graph value null and one graph having the value then the gap between the tooltip and the graph is too big. Need to show the tooltip correctly in that case as well.
[Please find jsfiddlelink here](http://jsfiddle.net/Lw476soe/)
I have attached the screenshots for the graph having both values and having null values.
Note: If the graph value is null or zero then we can't show the graph to that particular value.

http://jsfiddle.net/Lw476soe/

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    credits: { enabled: false },
    tooltip: {
      animation: false,
      followPointer: false,
      followTouchMove: false,
      headerFormat: `<span>
      {point.x}</span><br/>`,
      
      outside: true,
      backgroundColor: "#172733",
      borderColor: "#172733",
      borderRadius: 8,
      style: {
        color: "#FFFFFF",
        fontFamily: "Open Sans",
        fontSize: "12px",
        width: "500px",
      },
      enabled: true,
      useHTML: true,
      shared: true,
      snap: 2/5,
      pointer: false,
      colorByPoint: true,
      positioner: function(labelWidth, labelHeight, point) {
        return {
          x: point.plotX -5 ,
          y: point.negative ? point.plotY - point.h -10 : point.plotY - 10,
        };
      },
    },
    title: { text: null },
    legend: { enabled: false },
    chart: {
      float: "left",
      margin:[55, 24, 54, 55],
      height: 285,
      ignoreHiddenSeries: false,
    },
    xAxis: [
      {
        categories: ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"],
        min: 0.0,
        lineColor: "#EEF2F5",
        labels: {
          y: 26,
          align: "center",
          style: {
            backgroundColor: "#6F7981",
            color: "#6F7981",
            fontSize: "12px",
            labels: { reservespace: false },
            fontFamily:"Open Sans",
          },
        },
      },
    ],
    yAxis: [
      {
        visible: true,
        minTickInterval: 1,
        x: -16,
        style: {
          padding: 1,
        },
        title: { text: null },
        plotBands: [
          {
            to: -100000,
            from: 0,
            color: "#F5F7F9",
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
    plotOptions: {
      series: {
        stacking: "normal",
        states: { inactive: { opacity: 1 }, hover: { enabled: false } },
        lineWidth: 24,
        pointWidth: 24,
        pointPadding: 0,
        groupPadding: 0,
        stickyTracking: false,
      },
      column: {
        customRadius:  2,
      },
    },
    series:[
            {
              name: "Column",
              color: "green",
              borderColor: "green",
              type: "column",
              data: [10, 6, -7, 15, -2, null, -8, 0.5, -0.8, null, -1, 14],
              borderRadius: 0,
              minPointLength: 0,
            },
            {
              name: "Scatter",
              color: "blue",
              data: [10, -6, 7, null, -8, 16, null, -0.8, 0.5, -5, null, 12],
              lineWidth: 0,
              marker: {
                symbol: "circle",
                enabled: true,
                radius: 8,
              },
              states: {
                hover: {
                  lineWidthPlus: 0,
                },
              },
              borderRadius: 0,
              minPointLength: 0,
            },
          ]
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div id="container"></div>
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please add your code **and** jsfiddle link into your question. It will be lost in comments.

Comment: Hi, please find the Jsfiddle link.. http://Jsfiddle.net/Lw476soe/

Comment: Did you not read my comment at all? As I said, put **code** and **jsfiddle** into the **question**

Comment: i have added now.. please check once

Comment: I have added the Jsfiddle link.. please refer once.. (Please find jsfiddle link here) is the Jsfiddle link

Answer (score 0):

It is caused by your custom logic in the `positioner` function. A point passed to that function is not always a column point. Please check the below idea of implementation which I hope will help.

```
positioner: function(labelWidth, labelHeight, point) {
  const chart = this.chart;
  const hoverPoint = chart.hoverPoint;

  let columnPoint;
  let scatterPoint;
  let yPos;
  // check if hivered point is scatter
  if (!hoverPoint.shapeArgs) {
    scatterPoint = hoverPoint;
    columnPoint = chart.series[0].points[hoverPoint.x];
  } else {
    scatterPoint = chart.series[1].points[hoverPoint.x];
    columnPoint = hoverPoint;
  }

  if ((columnPoint.plotY || 9e9) < (scatterPoint.plotY || 9e9)) {
    yPos = columnPoint.negative ?
      columnPoint.plotY - columnPoint.shapeArgs.height :
      columnPoint.plotY;

  } else {
    yPos = scatterPoint.plotY - scatterPoint.graphic.height;
  }

  return {
    x: point.plotX - 5,
    y: yPos + chart.container.offsetTop
  };
}
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/m8ug6f7j/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip.positioner

Comment: Thanks for your Answer ppotaczek.. but in this case two graphs contains values tooltip is not aligned properly. I need to show the tooltip for postive values at the top end of the graph and for the negative values need to show tooltip on xaxis.

Comment: Hi @Sandhya, Please check this example: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/sodbfLz5/ Is that something that you want to achieve?